# How do I disable the button wrapper for jquery-ui-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

See this [sample page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/kuzando/datepicker/a.html).

The icon I want to be using is this:

[image]

The icon, as shown on the page, looks like this:

[image]

How can I make DatePicker use my original icon without modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`buttonImageOnly` property](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-buttonImageOnly) to `true`, like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   showOn: 'button', 
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/kuzando/datepicker/calendar.png'
});
```

[From the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-buttonImageOnly):

> **buttonImageOnly**: Set to true to place an image after the field to use as the trigger without it appearing on a button.

Comment: In the age of Stack Overflow, I do less and less of RFTM-ing. Thanks :)